# Simple Python HTTP Server for communication with jsonp

Tags: jquery, python, jsonp, basehttpserver

I'm trying to exchange data using jsonp between a python server and a webbrowser. The client side looks like this (using jQuery) and works just fine:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:8888/url/here?callback=?', {
      key: 'value',
      otherKey: 'otherValue'
    }, function(data){
         // Handles the callback when the data returns
          // $.each( data.items, function( antwort, item ) {
          // $("div.test").text(item.text);
          // })
          $("div.test").text('Success');
          console.log( data );
          $("div.test").text(data.antwort);
          // $.each(synval.terms, function(tkey, tval){
          //      $("div.test").text(tval.term);
    });

});
```

After the initial init lines the python server socket reaches a string like this:

```
GET /url/here?callback=jQuery111306895637936108335_1435907413063&key=value&otherKey=otherValue&_=143
```

Now I would like to return a string like this (with 'reply' containing 'that is a test':

```
    if data.find("jQuery") <> -1:
        json_header = data[data.find("jQuery"): data.find("&")]
        reply = json_header + "({\"reply\": \"that is a test\"})\n"  
        conn.send(reply)
```

For the communication I use a simple socket right now. But that works not really good. I searched for a little more high level solution. So I would like to use BaseHTTPServer now and subclass do_GET(self) instead. But I don't know how to realize the communication above. Can anybody help?

Comment: The reason I would like to use BaseHTTPServer is, that I found this example: http://fraka6.blogspot.de/2013/05/the-simple-python-server-example.html

Comment: I wouldn't really suggest using BaseHTTPServer. [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) is simpler. [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/) scales better.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution. You can get the request paramters by using self.path and reply by using self.request.sendall(). Here is the code:

```
#handle GET command
def do_GET(self):
    if format == 'json':  
        print "Anfrage erhalten "
        print self.path
        print json.dumps({'antwort':'das ist ein Test'})

        data=self.path
        json_header = data[data.find("jQuery"): data.find("&")]
        reply = json_header + "({\"antwort\": \"das ist ein Test\"})\n"  
        print (reply)
        self.request.sendall(reply)
```